# libPocoMongoDB.so.71: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: mongodb, poco, poco-libraries

I am using poco library to connect to mongodb. My code is getting compiled but while running out file it is giving me the below error

```
./test_mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libPocoMongoDB.so.71: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libPocoMongoDB.so.71 is already existing at /usr/local/lib

Here is my c++ code

```
#include "Poco/MongoDB/MongoDB.h"
#include "Poco/MongoDB/Connection.h"
#include "Poco/MongoDB/Database.h"
#include "Poco/MongoDB/Cursor.h"
#include "Poco/MongoDB/Array.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{


    try
    {
            Poco::MongoDB::Connection connection("localhost", 27017);
    }
    catch (Poco::Exception& exc)
    {
            std::cerr << exc.displayText() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

I compiled it using below command

```
g++ -o test_mongo test_mongo.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib/ -lPocoMongoDB -lPocoNet -lPocoFoundation
```

Comment: Can you try these commands: "ldconfig -v|grep libPocoMongoDB" and see if the lib is found, and "ldd /usr/local/lib/libPocoMongoDB.so.71" to see if there is missing dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. I tried ldconfig command and it found all the dependencies. Plus also found one more way to do it, just move all the libraries from /usr/local/lib to /usr/lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to resolve it

1. Try the ldconfig command.
2. Just move all the libraries from /usr/local/lib to /usr/lib.